# Gradle wrapper properties null pointer exception

Tags: gradle, nullpointerexception, synchronization, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

I get null pointer exception and I can't sync my project. Please help me fix this error as I cannot sync my own projects.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-bin.zip
```

Here is the Logcat:

```
Error:Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.normalizeAndCheck(UnixPath.java:77)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.<init>(UnixPath.java:71)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.getPath(UnixFileSystem.java:281)
at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
```

Comment: Check to see if you have a compatible JDK installed. Gradle gets some weird issues on Java 10.